# Excel: Files without extension created

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't know what happend, but I have an Excel file (`test.xls`) which is saved with random(?) name and without extension X times a day..

[image]

What does it mean? Is it created when the Excel fails? Sould it be some kind of file backup? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answer to your question.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814068 - description of the way that Excel saves files

1. Excel creates a randomly named temporary file (for example, Cedd4100 with no file name extension) in the destination folder that you specified in the Save As dialog box. The whole workbook is written to the temporary file.
2. If changes are being saved to an existing file, Excel deletes the original file.
3. Excel renames the temporary file. Excel gives the temporary file the file name that you specified (such as Book1.xls) in the Save As dialog box.

So the problem is in **file system permissions**. Try to save in your home directory.